# Proof of the strong law of large numbers for bernoulli random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

[image]

In the proof, could someone explain how we get from the second to the third line? I.e. how do we drop the intersection, and does it work for union?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the sets over which you take the intersection are descending.

If $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset \ldots$ then $P(\bigcap_i A_i) = \lim \limits_{i \to \infty} P(A_i)$ by upper continuity of finite measures. Since the sequence $P(A_i)$ is bounded by $1$ and nonincreasing, its limit is $1$ iff the sequence is constant $1$.

**Edit:** It's actually not necessary for the sets to be decreasing. By monotonicity of measures, $P(\bigcap A_i) \le P(A_i)$ for all $i$, so $P(\bigcap A_i) = 1$ implies $P(A_i) = 1$ for all $i$.

Conversely, if $P(A_i) = 1$ for all $i$, then $P((\bigcap A_i)^c) = P(\bigcup A_i^c) \le \sum P(A_i^c) = 0$, i.e. $P(\bigcap A_i) = 1$.

Comment: why do we need a decreasing sequence? say $P(\cap_i A_i) = 1$, then wouldn't $P(A_i) = 1$ for all $i$, else if say $P(A_j) \not = 1$ then surely we can't we have $P(\cap_i A_i) = 1$?

Comment: You actually need to prove the other direction, i.e. if $P(A_i) = 1$ for all $i$, then also the probability of the intersection is $1$. But it is correct that you don't need the sets to be decreasing for this. Simply consider complements and the subadditivity of the measure.

Comment: I still don't follow excatly why you need decreasing sets for your direction, i.e. for a general (non decreasing) $A_i$, if $P(\cap_iA_i) = 1$, then $P(A_i) = 1$. Why does this fail if $A_i$ are not decreasing?

Comment: It's not necessary. I've edited my answer.

Comment: did you mean intersection rather than union there?

Comment: Yes, now everything should be fine.

Comment: OK Thanks, and similarly, if we had $P(\cup A_i) = 0$ we can conclude that $P(A_i) = 0$ for every $i$?

Comment: That is correct.